# Get a variable from an abstract class

Tags: java, minecraft

Basicly i want to get the name of the map that is played from the "World.class", in a string on my main mod class...

```
    public abstract class World implements IBlockAccess{
    protected WorldInfo worldInfo;
    //=====OtherStuff=====
    public World(ISaveHandler par1ISaveHandler, String par2Str, WorldSettings par3WorldSettings, WorldProvider par4WorldProvider, Profiler par5Profiler, ILogAgent par6ILogAgent)
        {
        this.worldInfo.setWorldName(par2Str);
        }
    //=====OtherStuff=====
}
```

i created a class in the same package with this one

```
public class World_Spy extends World{

    public World_Spy(ISaveHandler par1iSaveHandler, String par2Str,
            WorldProvider par3WorldProvider, WorldSettings par4WorldSettings,
            Profiler par5Profiler, ILogAgent par6iLogAgent) {
        super(par1iSaveHandler, par2Str, par3WorldProvider, par4WorldSettings,
                par5Profiler, par6iLogAgent);
    }

    @Override
    protected IChunkProvider createChunkProvider() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Entity getEntityByID(int i) {
        return null;
    }


    String TheName = "";
    public void gotIt(){
        TheName = this.worldInfo.getWorldName();
        System.out.println(TheName);
    }

}
```

and i call it from my main class with:

```
World_Spy WName = new World_Spy(null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

but it chrashes on startup...
any ideas?

Comment: `implements IBlockAccess` -- LOL. Gotta love this!

Answer (score 1):

World is not a static class... you need an instance of a World compatible object to get the name.  One way to get an instance of a World and then the name:

```
World world = Minecraft.getMinecraft().isIntegratedServerRunning() ? mc.getIntegratedServer().worldServerForDimension(Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.dimension) : Minecraft.getMinecraft().theWorld;
String worldName = world.getWorldInfo().getWorldName();
```

This code should work client-side.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initalized `worldInfo`

```
protected WorldInfo worldInfo; // initialization MISSING!
```

So, when you try to instantiate `World_Spy` which in turn calls its parent class constructor `World()` you get a `NullPointerException` at

```
this.worldInfo.setWorldName(par2Str); // NullPointerException here
```

To resolve the issue simply provide an instance

```
protected WorldInfo worldInfo = new WorldInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it "crashes" by throwing `NullPointerException` here:

`this.worldInfo.setWorldName(par2Str);`

Indeed variable `worldInfo` was never initialized by you try to call its method `setWorldName()`. Since the variable is `null` at this point throwing `NullPointerException` sounds reasonable.

In java (exactly like in all other programming languages I know) you have to initialize variable before using it. Indeed primitive types are initialized by default using some kind of "normal" value. However variables of custom types are initialized to `null` that may confuse beginners.

To initialize you have to use `new` keyword following by constructor call:

`worldInfo = new WorldInfo();`

now you can call setters and other methods of `worldInfo`.